ctd change bond future
I do not work in the industry and I don't really have the data to explore that but was wondering if CTD changes happens often in the US bond future market?
Are there particular years where it happened a lot and on which contracts does it happen the most?
Also when it happens is it because there's high vol in the bond market? or the fed is hiking/cutting rates aggressively?

Without any specific knowledge of the particular bond market in question: assume the synthetic bond underlying the future has a duration which the deliverable bonds durations are scattered around. If the yield curve is upward (downward) sloping, the CTD should be one of the longer (shorter) duration bonds. The probability for a CTD change should be the highest when the yield curve is flat and its slope is volatilile.

CTD changes do happen from time to time  but as opposed to anything to do with switch options etc being excercised, due to very high volatilitly, it's due to more 'boring factors':

Some of these being the deliverable basket aging with time changing the deliverables into a contract.
Another being new issues which become the CTD.
Bonds with similar BNOCs becoming mildly cheaper to deliver.

Generally for most bond futures contracts the notional coupon is quite high say 6%, so the lowest duration bonds tend to be CTD  and as they age they will drop out of being eligible to be delivered (point 1).
Certain bond futures such as US (bond) have fairly dense baskets so the CTD may flick between the cheapest two or three bonds.
High vol, changes in Tsy issuance, curve changes etc. All impact the bases. Also repo and specialness are important.
